# Telescoping series- find a closed formula for $a_{k}$

Tags: calculus, closed-form, telescopic-series

I have a question from my discrete mathematics class. The prompt is as follows:

$\textit{Using the idea of a telescoping series, find a closed formula for $a_{k}$ if ...}$

$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{k} = 3n^{2} + 5n$

I don't understand how to solve this problem. I though the idea of a telescoping series was that if you write out the whole sum from $k = 1$ to $n$, the inner pieces cancel each other out. That doesn't work if we're adding $5n$ instead of subtracting something.

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you just write $a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = (3(n+1)^2+5(n+1))-(3n^2+5n) =6n+8$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show with telescoping sums that

$$a_n-a_1=\sum_{k=2}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})$$

And recall that

$$\sum(x+y)=\left(\sum x\right)+\left(\sum y\right)$$